# How to manage HTTP cache expiration from a suite of REST services

Tags: java, http, rest, caching

I have 30 REST services implemented in Java on the server side of a web app.  They all have hard coded cache expiration settings that are put into the HTTP response headers.  What is the best practice to manage these settings?

- keep them hard coded?
- have a config file to manage the settings if they need to change?
- keep them in a DB table by service name?
- are there existing frameworks that help manage this?

I do have some data that is quite static and very unlikely to change and then also data that I do not want cached at all.

I have searched, SO and I don't see an existing question like this.

**EDIT:** This is one of the constraints of a [RESTful API as defined by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).  A client should be able to cache certain data recived by the server.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming each service has a different, but fixed cache time.  If you ever find a need to change them I'd make them configurable, either in a properties file or part of the servlet config.  Database seems overkill and lookup would take time.

If the settings change at the request parameter level not just the service level, they probably need to be built as part of the response as they are now.  Either way, you probably want to do your own independent caching server side.